# Check periodicity of value in a Pandas Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas dataframe with three columns like that :

| Time | Code | Id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10:10:00 | Rx | 11 |
| 10:10:01 | Tx | 11 |
| 10:10:02 | Rx | 12 |
| 10:10:04 | Tx | 12 |
| 10:10:06 | Rx | 13 |
| 10:10:07 | Tx | 13 |
| 10:10:08 | Rx | 11 |
| 10:10:10 | Rx | 11 |

I want to check if for a `Rx` code if there is a `Tx` code just after and if the `id` is same for the `Rx` and `Tx`.
I want to get the row of duplicate `Rx` if there is.

In my example I want to throw the 10:10:10 Rx because it's duplicated.

I managed to do with for loop but I should'nt use for loop with Data Frame

```
    old_cell = None
    for index, row in pdo_df.iterrows():
        if old_cell is None:
            old_cell = row
        if row['Function_code'] == old_cell['Function_code']:
            print("----------------")
            print("Error :")
            print(old_cell)
            print(row)
            print("----------------")
        old_cell = row
```

My ideal output would be :

| Time | Code | Id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10:10:08 | Rx | 11 |

Because this `Rx` message is duplicated. (there is no `Tx` after)

Comment: What's the logic for duplicates here? within the same minute?

Comment: It must be a Tx after a Rx, the problem here is : There are two Rx next.

Comment: so do you want to drop both dupes or the single? can you add your ideal output?

Comment: I added my ideal output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method shift help you look at the value of the last row. This code detect then all the duplicates :

```
df[
    (df["Code"] == df["Code"].shift()) &
    (df["Id"] == df["Id"].shift()) 
    ]
```

Following the same logic, if we take the opposite of the last code, you have your dataframe without those duplicates :

```
df[
    ~((df["Code"] == df["Code"].shift()) &
    (df["Id"] == df["Id"].shift()) )
    ]
```

Comment: There is a problem in the line `(df["Id"] == df["Id"].shift())` I want th check Id 2 by 2, not one with the previous.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 2 by 2. If you do not want to check with previous line, but with the line before, you can use `(df["Id"] == df["Id"].shift(2))`. Shift take as argument the relative position of the line you want to target

Comment: No, it's not that, it's the two first row then the third and fourth etc. But never the second and the third. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72684897/compare-even-and-odd-rows-in-a-pandas-data-frame)

Comment: Then assume the index of your dataframe is starting at 0 and is incrementing by 1 (else you can reset him using `reset_index(drop=True)`, you can check the index to do it 2 by 2. Something like `df[
    ~((df["Code"] == df["Code"].shift()) &
    (df["Id"] == df["Id"].shift()) ) &
    (df.index % 2 == 1)
    ]`