# Compare even and odd rows in a Pandas Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, compare

I have a data frame like that :

| Index | Time | Id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 10:10:00 | 11 |
| 1 | 10:10:01 | 12 |
| 2 | 10:10:02 | 12 |
| 3 | 10:10:04 | 12 |
| 4 | 10:10:06 | 13 |
| 5 | 10:10:07 | 13 |
| 6 | 10:10:08 | 11 |
| 7 | 10:10:10 | 11 |
| 8 | 10:10:12 | 11 |
| 9 | 10:10:14 | 13 |

I want to compare `id` column for each pairs. So between the row `0` and `1`, between the row `2` and `3` etc.
In others words I want to compare even rows with odd rows and keep same `id` pairs rows.

My ideal output would be :

| Index | Time | Id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 10:10:02 | 12 |
| 3 | 10:10:04 | 12 |
| 4 | 10:10:06 | 13 |
| 5 | 10:10:07 | 13 |
| 6 | 10:10:08 | 11 |
| 7 | 10:10:10 | 11 |

I tried that but it did not work :

```
df = df[
    df[::2]["id"] ==df[1::2]["id"]
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `GroupBy.transform` approach:

```
# for each pair, is there only one kind of Id?
out = df[df.groupby(np.arange(len(df))//2)['Id'].transform('nunique').eq(1)]
```

Or, more efficient, using the underlying numpy array:

```
# convert to numpy
a = df['Id'].to_numpy()

# are the odds equal to evens?
out = df[np.repeat((a[::2]==a[1::2]), 2)]
```

output:

```
   Index      Time  Id
2      2  10:10:02  12
3      3  10:10:04  12
4      4  10:10:06  13
5      5  10:10:07  13
6      6  10:10:08  11
7      7  10:10:10  11
```